# After editing CSV file, size increases

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, libreoffice-calc

i'm trying to edit an CSV file. The main CSV file is 2.466KB after i downloaded it.

After i increased all Prices in one Collumn, and saved it as an .CSV file, the file size increased to 51,252MB.

I Edited the CSV file with the Libre Office, and Excel. On both increased the Size of it.

I tried to clear the Formats in Excel, but size was almost the same.

Is there a Method, how to import, Edit and Export as CSV file, without any big file size increase?

Thank you.

Comment: The reason might very likely be that there are empty rows that fill up space somehow. If you open the CSV, can you scroll all the way to the bottom with a lot of empty rows? Then that's the culprit, try delete the empty rows and save the file again.

Comment: Open your CSV file in Notepad or something similar and use the scroll bars to go right to the end.
Is there a huge space between the end of your data and the bottom of the file?

It sounds as though you have something (possibly formats) in a cell or cells way beyond the end of your actual data. Excel is ignoring this when you save as a .xls / .xlsx file, but acknowledging it as a valid cell (albeit empty) when you save as a .csv. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244435